# How to install Crunch Wordlist?

Tags: software-installation

How to install Crunch Wordlist on 12.10 32-bit?

[Crunch 3.4 Wordlist](http://sourceforge.net/projects/crunch-wordlist/)

I used

```
tar -zxvf crunch-3.4.tgz
cd crunch-3.4
sudo make
sudo makeinstall
```

A directory /pentest/passwords/crunch was created
but I cannot seem to know how to run Crunch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, Problem solved

I just need to go to the directory and then use ./crunch

```
cd /pentest/passwords/crunch
./crunch
```

Comment: You forgot to do `$ make install`